# Can we pass arguments to an instance variable?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, parameter-passing, artificial-intelligence

```
def select_action(self, state):
    probs = F.softmax(self.model(Variable(state, volatile = True))*100) # T=100
    action = probs.multinomial()
    return action.data[0,0]
```

self.model(...), where self.model is an instance of the Network class. How can there be parentheses after self.model if it is an instance variable and not a method, and we also aren't creating a new object? What exactly are the parentheses doing, and what are the parameters between the parentheses for?

Comment: Instances of a class can be callable objects, just like a function, if the class implements the `__call__()` method.

Comment: We haven't seen where `model` is defined. If its a `def model(self, ...)` then its clearly an instance method. As mentioned, anything that implements the `__call__` method can be called like a fucntion. In fact, functions are objects that implement `__call__`.

Comment: class Dqn():
    
    def __init__(self, input_size, nb_action, gamma):
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.reward_window = []
        self.model = Network(input_size, nb_action)
        self.memory = ReplayMemory(100000)
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr = 0.001)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `self.model` may be an instance "variable", but it happens to be a **callable** one (since, as you note, it is itself an instance of `Network`, and that must implement `__call__`)

While attributes on an instance are often "simple" types like `int` or `str`, there is no reason they cannot be more "complex" things like functions, or types, or other callable things.

Comment: class Dqn():
    
    def __init__(self, input_size, nb_action, gamma):
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.reward_window = []
       **self.model = Network(input_size, nb_action)**
        self.memory = ReplayMemory(100000)
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr = 0.001)